# Группировка RecyclerView Android

Tags: java, android, list, recyclerview

Здрaвcтвуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне сгруппировать recyclerview? Цифры слева на фото -это семестры. Хочу сгруппировать по семестрам.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

            if (array.length()!=0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject raspObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    MarksStudent marksStudent = new MarksStudent();
                    marksStudent.setMarksemestr(raspObject.getString("semectr"));
                    marksStudent.setMarkpredmet(raspObject.getString("predmet"));
                    marksStudent.setMarktype(raspObject.getString("typeexam"));
                    marksStudent.setOcenka(raspObject.getString("ocenka"));
                    arrayList.add(marksStudent);
                }
                marksAdapter = new MarksAdapter(getContext(), arrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(marksAdapter);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Группировка я так понимаю требуется визуальная. Для этих целей вам нужно в разметке добавить какое-то view определенного размера или сетить к элементу списка марджин сверху/снизу программно чтобы как-то отделить один семестр от другого. Вообще по логике, в вашем вопросе не хватает кода адаптера списка который занимается выводом данных. А именно метода занимающегося заполнением элемента данными:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
}
```

В конструктор помимо всякого-разного вы передаете массив состоящий из объектов класса `MarksStudent`. У этого класса (который вы опять таки не приводите) есть поле что-то типа `marksSemestr` которое хранит значение семестра которое в вышеуказанном методе вам нужно проверять и либо как уже говорилось раннее сетить марджин либо делать видимым какой-то view. Получаем элемент для отображения:

```
MarksStudent marksStudent = this.arrayList.get(position)
```

дальше проверяем если предыдущий элемент массива если он есть имеет поле семестра меньше чем у текущего то делаем видимой часть отвечающую за отступ:

```
if(position != 0 && marksStudent.getMarksemestr() > this.arrayList.get(position-1).getMarksemestr()){
holder.divider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
holder.divider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

другой вариант - увеличение отступа программно:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(0,20,0,0); // left, top, right, bottom
holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Стоит учитывать что здесь  `params.setMargins(0,20,0,0);` сетятся новые марджины для элемента списка и есть вероятность что ваши установленные отступы могут слететь. Поэтому я думаю вместо 0 имеет смысл установить ваши отступы если они есть.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!

Comment: @GRAND, был рад помочь :D

Comment: Извините, а можно добавить какой нибудь готовый Linear Layout вместо отступов, чтобы показать семестр? @Andrew

Comment: да в разметке item списка добавьте такой контейнер в самом верху чтобы он был, я просто не знаю как выглядит ваш элемент в xml)) просто смотрите через превью и поместите такой контейнер, добавьте id и потом показывайте там где нужно, так же по дефолту установите видимость как gone

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую